# How can I burn many movies to a video DVD?

Tags: windows-7, video, dvd, avi, dvd-burning

I once bought a DVD containing four 90-minute-long movies. Now I'm trying to write such a DVD, but don't know how to do it.

I tried to use DVD-Flick, but it says the disc is 98% used for a single 90-minute movie. My movies are 700MB dvdrips (AVI).

How can I put four movies on one disc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four 90 minute movies (for a total of 6 hours of film) would result in very poor picture quality on a single 4.6GB DVD.

A typical writable DVD is rated for approximately 2 hours of "good" quality video and generally film studios use dual layers to get more "film" on a DVD so have up to around 9GB available for film data.

The reason why the films only take up 700MB on your hard drive is that they are compressed using a newer higher quality compression method that takes up less space, effectively when you convert to DVD you are expanding it from one high compression algorithm to a another lower compression algorithm (a process known as transcoding).

If you absolutely must fit all four of those films on to one DVD then you can do this in DVD Flick by opening your project, selecting `Project Settings` on the top bar, then in the window that shows up you can play with the `Target Bitrate` to adjust the video quality:

[image]

[image]

Simply turn down the bitrate until all the video fits on the disc.

Comment: I saw that Two ninty minute movies on a 4.6GB disc works perfect without any quality loss

Answer (score 0):

I use [Super DVD Creator](http://www.alldj.com/sdvdc/download.htm) which is pretty cool and the feature it has I like them a lot.

**Some Feture of Sper DVD creator are:**

```
1: Support many formats as(Avi, RM, Wmv, Avi, Divx, Xvid, Mpeg, VOB files).     
2: It can convert these formats to VOB which supports the home DVD player.   
3: No doubt after convert in .VOB you can burn them on DVD.  
4: Add DVD Subtitle files to DVD with subtitle.  
5: Create DVD chapter menu just one click.
```

If you are looking for a free software for this then [Sothink DVD Creator](http://www.sothinkmedia.com/movie-dvd-maker/) may be helpful for you.
Sothink has many good features to help you:

```
1: Create DVD from almost all video formats.
2: Burn DVD movies on all DVD discs, like DVD–5 and DVD–9 etc.
3: Cut unwanted clips, auto create chapters, add external subtitle.
```

Comment: Please down-voter tell me the reason of your down-vote?

Comment: The response looks like an advertisement. You do not show how your program answers the OPs question, you just copied all the features from it's website and pasted them in an unhelpful answer.

Comment: @music2myear I edited the answer with a free tool link is now it in right way or not?

Comment: It is better, at least it doesn't look like an advertisement now. I've canceled my downvote. To make it even better, show how this program will do specifically what Pallavan wants it to do. Then you'll start getting upvotes.

Comment: @music2myear edited more I would highly thankful if you take a look for any edit. thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Nero burner software and when you burn the disc 
try to choose the disc format in standard quality movies.
But i think its not gonna work unless you burn as a data disc because for the movie disc it have time limitation. It doesn't matter on the movies size, it is depend on the movie time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't burn that much to the DVD in the DVD format, you'll probably find that the DVD you had that had 4 90min films on it was recorded in video CD format or possibly as mp4 or avi or one of the many many other choices.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would write them into DVD disc as data files.
If your player supports divx,avi etc... formats you can watch them as they are...
This is what I do for my huge .avi (BDrip,BRrip,DVDrip etc...) movie collection.